# Google apps script html to spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am learning google apps script at the moment by myself.

I have been trying to get someone's mail and append it to a google spreadsheets.

My code.gs looks actually like this:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
};

function addEmail (mail) {
  var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1k3vWmg9859mYykNNl0xDWoR_LUhnvLlq1qW8kSRuL_Q").getSheetByName("Sheeet1");
  mysheet.appendRow(mail);
};
```

And my html file looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </body>
  <label for="getUserMail">Type your mail here</label> <input type="text" id="getUserMail">
  <button id="trigger">Submit!</button>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("trigger").addEventListener("click",sendMailToCode);
    function sendMailToCode () {
     var umail = document.getElementById("getUserMail");
     google.script.run.addEmail(umail);
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work. I have tried doing multiple stuff to fix it, even adding a  tag on html but it does not save the value on the spreadsheet. Could someone please give an advice?

Comment: Is the sheet name `Sheeet1 `correct ? (It looks to have an extra `e`. Anyway please add developers tools console (web browser) logs and Google Apps Script execution page logs textually.

Comment: Also fix the position of `</body>` (it "should" be immediately before `</html>`)

Comment: Hi Ruben. Thanks! I have fixed the position of body closing tag and the extra "e" on "Sheet1", but still doesn't work.
On the logs, everything is empty.

Comment: Are you using /exec or the /dev URLs? if you are using /exec you have to create a new version to make that change effective on a web app.

Comment: I am publishing a new version after finishing changes and deploying it. So yes, I did use the /exec

Comment: It's not clear what you mean (there isn't a "publish" command in the Google Apps Script editor). Are you using the Google Apps Script editor in English?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

This will append the html to the sheet but it will not render it.

```
    function addEmail (mail='<html><head><basetarget="_top"></head><body><h1>hello</h1></body><labelfor="getUserMail">Typeyourmailhere</label><inputtype="text"id="getUserMail"><buttonid="trigger">Submit!</button><script>document.getElementById("trigger").addEventListener("click",sendMailToCode);functionsendMailToCode(){varumail=document.getElementById("getUserMail");google.script.run.addEmail(umail);};</script></html>') {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
      sh.appendRow([mail]);
    }
```

[appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Reading the description of row contents: "An **array** of values to insert after the last row in the sheet."